# Refactor suggestion

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this code and I didn't like how the result was structured. I would like some refactoring suggestion to make it less repetitive. Don't worry, the variable names used here are just an example.

```
plans_ids_with_attribute = [3024, 3045, 3060]   

plans_without_attribute = [
    plan for plan in plans if plan.id not in plans_ids_with_attribute
]
plans_with_attribute = [plan for plan in plans if plan.id in plans_ids_with_attribute]

first_sorted_example = sorted(
    plans_without_attribute, key=lambda p: p.weight, reverse=True
)
second_sorted_example = sorted(
    plans_with_attribute, key=lambda p: p.weight, reverse=True
)
sorted_plans = first_sorted_example + second_sorted_example
```

Comment: Please post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Rather than building two intermediate lists only to sort them into two more intermediate lists and finally concatenate them to produce the single list that's ordered the way you want, I'd suggest doing a single `sorted()` where you sort first on the id and then on the weight in order to produce the desired ordering all at once:

```
plans_ids_with_attribute = [3024, 3045, 3060]

sorted_plans = sorted(
    plans,
    key=lambda p: (p.id in plans_ids_with_attribute, -p.weight)
)
```

Since the key is a tuple, the first value (`p.id in plans_ids_with_attribute`) is compared first, and then the second value.  `False` comes before `True`, so you'll get all the non-attribute plans first, and those will be sorted by the second tuple value (the negative of the weight, so they'll go in descending order by the actual weight).

Not only is this a lot less code, it's less confusing to read IMO (as long as you already know how sort works with tuples) because you can see the sorting rules all in one place rather than having to sort through a bunch of individual operations and then reason about how they add up to the final result.  It's also more efficient, since you don't need to create copies of all the list items.